# Android GridLayout issues with Imageview

Tags: android, imageview, size, drawable, pixel

I am using a gridlayout to display a grid of differents pictures on my phone screen.

I set the number of column to ten but my phone only display 7 pictures. Picture 8 is cut and the others pictures are not even displayed on the screen.

Here is a screenshot of my phone ( dont pay attention to the app name, I am not using a gridview but a gridlayout ) :

[image: My screenshot on portrait]

[image: My screenshot on lanscape]

And here is my XML code :

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:columnCount="10"
android:rowCount="15"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blue" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/green" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/teen" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/purple" />  
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blue" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/green" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/teen" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/purple" /> 
     <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/teen" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/purple" /> 
 </GridLayout>
```

All my drawable are set to 72px * 72 px and my phone screen is 720 * 1280 px.

So theorically, by setting my number of column to 10 I should have exactly 10 pictures fitting perfectly with my phone.

Is there something wrong with my reasoning or with my imageview parameters ( layout width and height maybe ? ) ?

Thanks everybody !

Comment: Can you change the device orientation to vertical and post here what happens?

Comment: Ok.. I also see another problem now. You are using dp (in the first image view) which is different from pixels. It should be 72px, not 72dp. dp stands for density independent pixels which scales the image.

Comment: My Bad Sunil, I have posted the wrong XML file ( the old one, with de dp setting was just something I was trying ). It's corrected now, I also add the screenshot on landscape mode.

Comment: Ok.. so it recognizes all 10 in landscape and that works as expected. Can you make the width and height of the root grid layout to match parent. I'm kind just trying to see why you are getting this. If you are positive the pictures are 72x72px, then 10 of them should perfectly fit the screen.

Comment: I tried with match_parent and it is exactly the same ! Also, I have checked again, my drawable are 72px*72px

Comment: I got it ! I have put my drawable into the hdpi foler but my device is an xhdpi device ... Anyway ! Thank for your help Sunil !

Answer (score 0):

I have put drawable into the wrong folder ...

So it works now !